# Windows Authentication, authorization roles/users * & ? meaning

Tags: windows, authentication

I have been searching high and low for the correct explaination for the usage of ? and *.
I have noticed that I could deny access to all users by using:

```
<deny users="*"/>
```

Than if I want to allow a certain group I should add the next line above that:

```
<allow roles="NETWORKDNS\ROLE"/>
```

But where I am starting to lose track of what, what means, is when I see people using the ?, for example:

```
<allow roles="NETWORKDNS\?"/>
```

For me, this means, allow all users that **DO NOT** come from the NETWORKDNS, but I tested this in my enviroment, and this seems false.

In general, i learned:

(*) = everyone

(?) = no-one

But I am starting to get confused by the behaviour of IIS with these, they seems reversed, except when talking about users.
I couldn't find any explaination on MSDN or SO.

Does someone have a good reference link for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation for [allow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/acsd09b0(v%3Dvs.100)) and [deny](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/8aeskccd(v=vs.100)).

They have clearly defined the `users` attribute.

> Required String attribute.
>
> A comma-separated list of user names that are allowed access to the resource. A question mark (?) indicates that anonymous users are granted access to the resource. An asterisk (*) indicates that all users are granted access to the resource.

The question mark (?) refers to the anonymous users, i.e., non logged-in users on your site. Your understanding of asterisk (*) was correct in that it refers to all users.

**kasptom** shared this [link](https://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config) having example configs. The author also mentions the same definitions for * and ?.

**Edit**:

I missed that you were trying to use * and ? in the roles attribute. That is wrong. See the examples in the above links. You can use the users and roles attributes together to create for tightened access rules.

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer! I have been searching for the explanation on why the ? acts different than I thought it would, apparantly I have interperted it wrong from the start.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation of the [allow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/acsd09b0(v%3dvs.100)) and [deny](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/8aeskccd(v=vs.100)) attributes of the `authorization` element one can conclude that the second example (`<allow roles="NETWORKDNS\?"/>`) is simply **invalid**... or rather says: "Allow the role named *?* in the *NETWORKDNS*"

Lots of examples you can find under [this](https://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config) link, also [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/acsd09b0(v%3dvs.100))

Moreover, looking exactly at the [attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/acsd09b0(v%3dvs.100)#attributes) `roles` asterisk (*) and question mark (?) **are not valid** for this attribute